# Maximal Orthogonal Subset

Tags: linear-algebra

If $v= [2; 0; -1], w = [1; 3; 3], x = [6; 1; -3], y = [1; 0; 2],$ and $z = [2; -15,; -1]$,
what is the maximal orthogonal subset?

I found it to be $\{x,y,z\}$. Is that right?

What is the maximum number of non-zero orthogonal vectors that you can find in $\mathbb{R}^3$?
It looks like $3$.

What about $\mathbb{R}^n$?
From the pattern above, it looks like $n$.

Could someone explain the why?

Answer (score 1):

Given two vectors $x = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\\vdots \\ x_n\end{bmatrix}$ and $y = \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ \vdots \\ y_n \end{bmatrix}$, the vectors are orthogonal if

$\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i = 0$. So just go pairwise over $v,w,x,y,z$. Looks like you are correct though that $\lbrace x,y,z \rbrace$ is the maximal subset, though I didn't totally work this out.

As for your other question, orthogonal vectors are perpendicular. It's easy to see that if you are in $\mathbb{R}^2$ you can only have two vectors which are perpendicular. Similarly, in $\mathbb{R}^3$ you can only have three perpendicular vectors. Orthogonality extends this notion of perpendicular to higher dimensions. So given that interpretation you can see that in $\mathbb{R}^n$ you can only have $n$ orthogonal vectors. You would need to add another dimension to the space to have an additional orthogonal vector, thus $n$ is maximal. (This is by no means a proof.)

It's also easy to see when you consider the vectors $e_i = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\  \vdots \\ 0 \\ 1 \\0 \\ \vdots \\ 0\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, where the 1 is in the $i$th place and everything else is zero. For $1 \leq i \leq n$ all the $e_i$ are orthogonal (easy to verify from the definition) and easy to think about in low dimensional apce.

Answer (score 1):

The notion of of orthogonality (or scalar product) can be extended by the notion of bilinear form, which (in case the respective quadratic form is positive-definite) works similarly as the classical "dot product" (more on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space).

The crucial property is the bilinearity of the form:

1) it implies that two nonzero linearly dependent vectors cannot be orthogonal
2) it provides you with the Gramm-Schmidt process https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process, which permits you to obtain an orthogonal sequence from any given basis of the finite-dimensional space.

Hence to answer to your question: yes, in $\mathbb{R}^n$, there always exists an orthogonal basis.

Answer (score 1):

Given several non-zero vectors, if they are orthogonal (one to another), then they are linearly independent. So their number cannot exceed  $ n $  if they are in  $ \mathbb{R}^n $ .
Moreover, every euclidian space has an orthonormal basis.